# How to connect Cloudfare to an EC2 Amazon server?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

Im running an Amazon EC2 server with Ubuntu. I've installed Nginx and gone through the setup instructions provided [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04). The link has one of the chain of tutorials. I've done all the setup, and successfully connected my google provided domain to Cloudflare. My issue is that Cloudflare isn't connecting to the server. Whenever I type in my domain, it just shows "webpage not found". Is there another guide/resource I should be using? A book perhaps?

Comment: 1. Just enable Cloudflare as your DNS service provider, so that you can test out the basic functionality. 2. When everything works, change your Cloudflare configuration to enable more features like CDN/caching. Don't move too fast. Currently I think you didn't even configure DNS records properly and that requires a lot of reading on how to manage DNS records.

Comment: Thanks, ill go ahead and read up more on DNS records. I really haven't done much with DNS other than connecting my Domain from Google to Cloudflare.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your help. I... did not have it setup. I only had the domain redirect.  I didn't have my A type DNS records, only CNAME.

Comment: Luckily Cloudflare has extensive documentation to help you get started, https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/how-to/create-dns-records/ and you can use search engines to find more on Cloudflare/AWS.

Comment: For whoever comes upon this with the same question:

To be able to connect I needed to:
(1) Set up my domain with google and connect the Cloudflare nameserver to it
(2) On cloudfare setup the DNS for www.your_domain.com and your_domain.com under A type DNS to the public IPv4 of your server
(3) Have Nginx setup ^Link provided above
(4) Make sure to have certbot activated (Tutorial found on Digital Ocean)

I don't know if this is for all websites, but mine was a .dev, so it required a certificate.

Comment: You can actually write/accept your own answer below to close the discussion.